# python subprocess.Popen vs shlex question

Tags: python, list, subprocess, pipe

my sub process command to search first off it only searches one directory that i wrote (s2) omits the first (s1). second i was doing some reading on python docs and got confused.

my code

```
def search_entry(self, widget):
            s1 = subprocess.Popen(['find', '/home/bludiescript/tv-shows', '-type', 'f'], shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
            s2 = subprocess.Popen(['find', '/media/FreeAgent\ GoFlex\ Drive/tobins-media', '-type', 'f'],  stdin=s1.stdout, shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
            s1.stdout.close()
            self.contents = "\n".join(self.list)
            s2.communicate(self.contents)
```

what i got confused about was with the shlex module and how to use it in place of subprocess.Popen in my code and if it would even make sense.

so would some like this work better than what i have

```
cmd = 'find /media/FreeAgent\ GoFlex\ Drive/tobins-media -type f find /home/bludiescript/tv-shows -type f'
 spl = shlex.split(cmd)
 s1 = subprocess.Popen(spl, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
 self.contents = "\n".join(self.list)
        s1.communicate(self.contents)
```

thanks again for you input

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to run a pair of commands and join the output from them:

```
cmds = [
    'find /media/FreeAgent\ GoFlex\ Drive/tobins-media -type f',
    'find /home/bludiescript/tv-shows -type f'
]

ouput = '\n'.join(subprocess.check_output(shlex.split(cmd)) for cmd in cmds)
```

Comment: yes that is what i was looking for is there a reason why my original code wasn't working

Comment: In regards to your original attempt, something like this would have worked to capture the output of each command individually: `proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE); output = proc.communicate()[0]`. Refer to the [`subprocess` documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) for more detail on how it works.

Comment: again it still only searching the first find entry

Comment: My example runs both commands, as to their result, I have no idea if it's what you want or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try [`os.walk`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html) instead of invoking `find`. This will result in more robust code. The following is equivalent to your first invocation of `find`:

```
top = '/media/FreeAgent GoFlex Drive/tobins-media'
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(top):
    for filename in filenames:
        print os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
```

This doesn't answer the question, though.

Comment: well the only reason why i went with find command was because i figured i could link the text entry in the search bar i made essentially self.search = gtk.Entry() with the name of the file in the find command. but that is not working either i tried os.walk and it does list all the files below the directory  so its a step closer than how find was working